# Problem when upload apk to AppGallery Huawei

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect, huawei-account

While uploading apk to app gallery account I'm facing this error "Your App contains wallet functions. ­Please upload it again with a company account and provide the relevant qualification license or authorization.".

Please guide me how to fix this.

I every time release my apk, but same message and i do not understand what is means.